# Change grid column after every 3 posts in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I want to display my blog posts in a 3x2x3 grid layout where the first row has 3 posts, the second row has 2 posts, and the third row has 3 posts. My method is just repeating the `for loop` using `limit` and `offset` to filter it. Trying to figure out a more elegant method to do this without using so many `for loop`.

**Code**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        {% for post in site.posts limit: 3 %}
            <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4'>
                <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        {% for post in site.posts limit: 2 offset: 3 %}
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        {% for post in site.posts limit: 3 offset: 5 %}
            <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4'>
                <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [forloop.index](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/for-loops) to do this:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        {% for post in site.posts limit: 8 %}
            <div class='col-sm-6{% unless forloop.index == 4 or forloop.index == 5 %} col-md-4{% endunless %}'>
                <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

... but [cycle](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/iteration/) is even more elegant:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        {% for post in site.posts limit: 8 %}
            <div class='col-sm-6{% cycle "","",""," col-md-4"," col-md-4" %}'>
                <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

... however if you want to show off/show that you are a true programmer, you should use the mathematical function [modulo](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/modulo/) and start counting from zero with `forloop.index0`:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        {% for post in site.posts limit: 8 %}
            {% assign mod = forloop.index0 | modulo: 5 %}
            <div class='col-sm-6{% if mod == 3 or mod == 4 %} col-md-4{% endif %}'>
                <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: would the `forloop.index` allow for the alternating grid columns if I had 50+ posts?

Comment: yes, absolutely, as it is just the counter

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers! Much appreciated!!!